# How to enable crash report submission to iTunesConnect from iOS App?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I was using Evernote and it crash once, So after crashing I reopen it and it ask me for submit crash report to developer.

After some googling I have found in my iTunes Connect Account in Application detail there is one option called Crash reports.

So my conscience is that how to enable crash report submission in Application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the app asks for sending crash reports this has nothing to do with iTunes Connect.

The reports you see in iTunes Connect are send automatically by the phone (or iTunes?) when the user has agreed to send diagnostic reports when they set up their device. This happens automatically, you don't have to configure anything at all. Just go to iTunes Connect and get the crash reports.

But to be honest, iTunes Connect crash reports seem a little bit unreliable. If you see them at all it takes almost forever until you see them. Another culprit is that you have to check for new reports manually.

So Evernote, like basically everyone else, switched to a 3rd party service for crash reporting.
I use [crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com) in my own apps. But there are many others.

A good read might be Ray Wenderlichs [Overview of iOS Crash Reporting Tools: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1) and [Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/34050/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-2)

---

Some personal experience:

Since my apps don't crash often I usually see "Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown." in iTunes Connects crash reporter. But when I open the console of crashlytics is see 6 different crashes right now. Most of them affect only two or three people but it's good to be aware of new issues, even if few people are affected.

iTunes Connect does not show crash reports for prerelease versions of iOS. But it happened that I had a horrible bug in my app that lead to a crash instantly after people opened the settings of my app on a prerelease version of iOS. After the first crash report came in via crashlytics I fixed that bug and submitted an update. Because I didn't have time to test against the first betas it would have taken a while to be aware of this crash if I had relied solely on iTunes Connect.

Comment: +1 for Crashlytics. Depending on iTunes connect is hopeless. In an earlier version of our iPad app we couldn't even get the report from IC due to bugs on Apple's end which they had little interest in fixing.